# Pass lead from Javascript to Lightning component

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component, lightning-apps

I've got a lightning component in a visualforce page that is loaded like so:

```
  <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:MapApp", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:Map",
          { label : "" },
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
              // SOMETHING LIKE THIS? THIS DOESN'T WORK THOUGH
              cmp.set('v.leads', leads);
              cmp.set('v.map', document.getElementById('map'));
              cmp.set('v.markers', cmp.change());
              // END
          });
    });

    var lead = new SObjectModel.Lead(),
        leadList = document.getElementById('lead-list');

    function createTile (record) {
      return [record.get('FirstName'), ' ', record.get('LastName')].join('');
    }

    lead.retrieve(
      { orderby: [{ LastName: 'DESC' }], limit: 10 },
      function(error, records) {
        if (error) {
          alert(error.message);
        } else {
          leadList.innerHTML = records.map(createTile).join('');
        }
      }
    );
  </script>
```

How can I pass the leads found with `retrieve` to my `Map` component?

**Update**

My component looks like this:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/leaflet/leaflet.css"
                  scripts="/resource/leaflet/leaflet.js"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}" />

    <aura:attribute name="leads" type="Lead[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="map" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="markers" type="Object"/>

    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.leads}"
                  action="{!c.leadsChangeHandler}" />

    <div aura:id="map"></div>

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating the lightning component in the callback function of `lead.retrieve`?

```
    lead.retrieve(
  { orderby: [{ LastName: 'DESC' }], limit: 10 },
  function(error, records) {
    if (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    } else {
      leadList.innerHTML = records.map(createTile).join('');
      $Lightning.use("c:MapApp", function() {
         etc....
      });
    }
  }
);
```

**UPDATE**

I played around with this a little more, it seems you need to do a little more playing around with the retrieved remote object records before passing it to the lightning component.  Found that what you need to pass is the `_props` property, like so:
`lead.retrieve(
  { orderby: [{ LastName: 'DESC' }], limit: 10 },
  function(error, records) {
    if (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    } else {
      leadList.innerHTML = records.map(createTile).join('');
      var leadRecs = [];

                  records.forEach(function(rec){
                      leadRecs.push(rec._props);
                  });
      $Lightning.use("c:MapApp", function() {
          { label : "", "leads" : leadRecs},
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
          });
      });
    }
  }
);`

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: My component doesn't even load when I move it to the callback. Nothing telling in the way of error messages either.

Comment: In fact, it's this line that breaks the map entirely: `component.set('v.leads', records);`

Comment: Correction: that like returns ` [object Object]` and not the contents. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you would set your component attributes in the string of JSON params: `$Lightning.use("c:MapApp", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:Map",
          { label : "" , leads : records, etc.},`

Comment: @CD-RUM check the update.  Had to do a little remote objects research (never used them before :).

Comment: Trying it, I think we're on the right track but it's hard for me to confirm because I think my Lightning component isn't 100% yet.